# callback function doesn't not return content

Tags: node.js, etherpad

I have a problem, I did not find any solution for this.
This code is not working . Inside the callback function.  can you please solve my problem.

```
exports.eejsBlock_body = function (hook_name, args, cb) {
  customUtils.getOneValueSql(getQuery).then(function (returnData) {     
    args.content = args.content + eejs.require("ep_top_menu/templates/index.ejs", {"padname":returnData}, module);
    return cb();
    });
 };
```

Comment: Try `return cb(null, args.content);`

Comment: Not Working, I have changed return cb(); to return cb(null, args.content);

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.eejsBlock_body = function (hook_name, args, cb) {
  customUtils.getOneValueSql(getQuery).then(function (returnData) {     
    args.content = args.content + eejs.require("ep_top_menu/templates/index.ejs", {"padname":returnData}, module);
      return cb(null, args.content);
    });
 };
```

Then use :

```
eejsBlock_body(paramHook, paramArgs, function(err, content){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
   } else {
     console.log(content)
   }
 });
```

Comment: Hi,

I do not want to console content, I want pass content to file as a parameter.

Comment: So you can use :

if(err){
     return callback(err);
   } else {
     return callback (null, content)
   }

Comment: I have used same : exports.eejsBlock_body = function (hook_name, args, cb) {
  customUtils.getOneValueSql(getQuery).then(function (returnData) {     
    args.content = args.content + eejs.require("ep_top_menu/templates/index.ejs", {"padname":returnData}, module);
      return cb(null, args.content);
    });
 };

But not wroking

Comment: Did you try to console.log the data just to be sure that it's not empty?
Can you paste the function that use the callback of eejsBlock_body?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `eejsBlock_body` does not work with async changes to `args.content`. Do you need that query to run on the hook? Are you running the query just to get the pad name/id?

If that's the case, you could just put a placeholder (e.g.: `<span id='padId'/>`) on your `index.ejs`, and use the hook `postAceInit` to insert pad name into it:

```
exports.postAceInit = function(type, context) {
  $('#padId').text(clientVars.padId);
}
```